# More efficient keyframe animation in Flash CS4/5

Tags: flash, animation, flash-cs4, flash-cs5, keyframe

I'm doing a lot of keyframe masking of vines/flowers for a project I'm working on, and it looks really good but is, of course, very time consuming.

I'm curious if there's any techniques/tools for making these animations faster, and more importantly making them more editable later. I'm afraid I'm going to keyframe out entire sections of animation only for the client to say "Looks great, but can you speed it up just a touch?" and I'll have to rebuilt it all from scratch again.

Comment: Is this about ActionScript keyframe animation? If not, perhaps this may not be the best site to ask.

Comment: No, this is timeline animation in the Flash CS IDE. I know this may not be the best place to ask, but I know a lot of AS3 people run around here so I figured I might run into someone with some suggestions. I'm asking a couple other places too, and I'll add any good info I find elsewhere back here.

Comment: @John Hopefully you can make the vines using custom symbols and the Deco Tool, which should also allow you to animate, otherwise, I would recommend trying to use only 2 or 3 vine symbols reused a lot so you will only need to change those 2,3 vines as opposed to everything. Also, depending on your method of animation, keep track of the editable steps you're taking in the History Panel(CMD/Ctrl+F10) and save commands you can assign keyboard shorcuts to automate your workflow. Also consider having a look at JSFL and maybe look for Flash extensions on sites like http://ajarproductions.com/

Comment: as @BoltClock mentioned, this might be a question more suited for superuser.com, unless you want to animate the vines from code. Also, bare in mind that with the current Motion Tween(not Classic tween) and Motion Editor it's easier to rescale animation time-wise .

Comment: @George Profenza, Thanks for the tips, these are helpful. I'll explore and post more once I figure out what I'm going to do. Thanks!

Comment: @George, if you want to add your comments as an answer, I would be happy to mark them as accepted. Each part of your answer was helpful to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @John added expanded answer and examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At @John's suggestion here is the expanded comment as an answer.

Here are some ideas for animating vines/masks:

- Try using the **Deco Tool**

It has a preset called Vine Fill which can be animated, you can configure a few options and animate the fill. Hopefully it can be configured to suit your needs. 
Also you might want to play with the 3D brush preset, set a symbol to use as a mask and minimize the Spray area.

The Deco tools are powered by a nice prodecural C++ engine and you can create your own tools
using Javascript. The existing scripts will be in a location similar to this:

```
/Users/{yourUser}/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/Flash\ CS5/en_US/Configuration/ProcScripts
```

Unfortunately there isn't a documentation out there for the Procedural engine yet.

- Try creating the animation using only 2 or 3 symbols, but **reuse** them many times to create your masks. This way, you only update the animation 2,3 symbols and it will be reused.
- Find Steps in your workflow that can be saved from the **History Panel** (CMD/Ctrl+F10). Those steps can be saved as commands you can assign keyboard shortcuts to and automate/speed up your workflow
- Look for extensions that might aid your with your timeline. [Ajar Productions](http://ajarproductions.com/pages/) have a great set of free tools for CS4,CS5. Also you might find [Senocular's Distribute To Frames](http://senocular.com/flash/extensions/?entry=520) command handy.
- Try to pickup JSFL. You can find some basic steps in some of my older [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/orgicus/introduction-to-jsfl).
  I might have a few rough scripts that might help, like this [Copy Shape Tween As Graphic](http://disturbmedia.com/blog/post/playing-with-lines-shapes-and-time/)
  [image: whitney shape tween]

It just copies shape tween frames into one frame.

[Here](http://www.screencast.com/users/orgicus/folders/Jing/media/157b075e-b949-4d95-b7ca-c6cb86dc29d2) is an example on how you might use it for a mask animation.
[image: Copy graphics frame by frame]
If your vine path isn't very complex, you can copy a line/path as an animation
path for your mask symbol. Just draw a simple path on top, copy it to the clipboard
then paste it into the mask symbol's motion tween.
Notice in the recording that I am rescaling time for tween and using the onion skin
option to preview how the shapes overlap. If you use something like an oval and the 
use the **orient to path** option, you can get away with less symbols.

Also here's a little snippet you can save as AutoSpanLayers.jsfl and put it Flash's Commands folder so you can assign a keyboard shortcut to:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var tl  = doc.getTimeline();
tl.insertFrames((tl.layerCount*100),false);
for(var i = 0 ; i < tl.layerCount; i++){
    tl.setSelectedLayers(i,true);
    tl.insertBlankKeyframe(i+30);
    tl.insertKeyframe(i+1);
    tl.insertBlankKeyframe(i);
    tl.insertBlankKeyframe(0);
}
```

It's not very clean/fancy, but it's a starting point. This one spans the layers in your
current symbol and increments it. At this point you can't change the amount of frames it spans and for how long nicely. You need to change the (i+30) and the (i+1) bit. It's not a finished script.

but [here](http://www.screencast.com/users/orgicus/folders/Jing/media/d5bee098-a65d-49f4-91d3-f81d695716fd)'s an example of how you can use it. 
[image: AutoSpan Command Preview]

[Here](http://www.screencast.com/users/orgicus/folders/Jing/media/de09d518-e2a8-45e5-98ee-808a45cb4417) is another example to animate a vine mask. 
[image: Vine example]
Notice I'm using the Deco 3D Brush tool preset just to easily paint
group object I'll use for the mask. This is a lazy option, as it creates
lots of symbols and the Spray minimum is 10px so it's not very exact either,
but you get the picture.

Another important note is that my scripts haven't been thoroughly testes, so
do make some basic tests first, save often. I don't want to feel guilty for 
crashing Flash to often. This will probably happen when have a complex timeline.

HTH

Comment: Excellent comment. Very helpful. I've been doing flash animation a while and learned a bunch of new tricks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, for implying full animations you can use Tweening, see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUgNhESiPRM) tutorial.